# How to do a php validation check for an input outside of a form

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have an input outside of a form that I do validation with javascript, however I want back-end validation as well. The input I am referring to is basically an entry way to see a registration form. When the input value matches the value within the javascript it shows the registration form.

All I want is to figure out a way within my php code to check to see if the value of the input does not match the value within the php code, the person cannot submit the form.

Everything I have seen while trying to search for this only shows items within the same form. Does anyone have any idea how I would do this?

Let's say I want the php code to check to see if the value of the validate input = Entry, then I can submit the form.

```
<div id="validate">
            <label>Please provide your code</label>
            <input type="text" id="validate-input">
        </div>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="register">
<?php if (isset($error)){
    echo $error, '<br>';
}?>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="firstname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('firstname')); ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('lastname')); ?>" required>
            </div>
<input id="signinButton" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: You could use AJAX.

Comment: Outside a form, you will never see it on server side (only if you are using ajax)

Comment: Well, I already have javascript validation, so I am not sure how ajax would help? Please explain.

Comment: You should make a 2 Step form, First step `enter code form`, second `give access to user input form` if code was right

Comment: When the input is filled out you would send an AJAX request to a PHP script with the value in question. PHP would validate and then send a response.

Comment: Ajax would help because you send the input to your PHP server, validate it and return the validation status to your JS script. That's how Ajax works. Any time you need PHP functionality without a new page-load, Ajax will be the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that on your solution (showing form if...) the form can be posted with an browser develop tool anyway. Hidden forms can easly be shown today and also send.

Comment: So, I put my validate input within a form and then send it to a php file to check if the values match? How would I do the php check though? I am wanting it to stop another form from submitting if it doesn't match. This is the part that really confuses me, but realistically, the reason I am wanting to do this is in case someone turn JS off.

Comment: `How would I do the php check though?` sentence like that make helping very hard.  If i answer staight to that: check the given $_POST['fieldname'] against the expected code .

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve has been described. I am trying to eliminate users from registering by turning off javascript. The validation input I have is a front-end way of eliminating uninvited users to register to my site. Since this input is not within the same form as the registration, I am looking for a back-end or alternative measure to eliminate this.

Comment: Without JS and without a form you cannot validate lone inputs. PHP would need a form.

Comment: I can make the single input into a form. That is not an issue. I just do not know how to check it and then disable the other form from submitting if it does not equal the value I am requiring to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can use an AJAX call and simply serialize the data yourself, it doens't need to be part of a form.  jQuery makes it easy, rather than using the `.serialize()` method, you can instead use '.param()' method on an object or array of whatever params you want, here's an example...

**Script to include with form...**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#validate-input').on('change',function(){
        var data = {}
        data.validate-input = $('#validate-input').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            cache: false, 
            url: '/validation.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: jQuery.param(data),  // results in 'validate-input=abc123' string
            success: function(response){
                // 200 HTTP response - enable submit
                $('signinButton').attr('disabled',false);
                alert('Code accepted, submit away!');
            },
            error: function(response){
                // do nothing, bad code
            }
        };
    });
});
```

**PHP Validation Script** (`/validation.php`)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['validate-input']) && $_POST['validate-input'] == $_SESSION['validate-code']) {
    http_response_code(200);
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
}
```

The above will result in an `event` being added to your Validate Code field, so every time someone changes the value there (every time they type a character), an AJAX call will be made in the background to the validation script on the server. The moment the code matches the one on the server, the Submit button will be enabled automatically, and a popup will tell them they're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to check this so that the registration form cannot be submitted unless the validation-input = Entry or something else?

Comment: Just set up your submit button like so: `<input id="signinButton" type="submit" value="Register" disabled="disabled">` then, where I've included the `success`, add the following: `$('signinButton').attr('disabled',false);`  What that does is starts your form off with a disabled submit button, and only enables it when the validation is successful.

Comment: You'll have to maintain state on the server side, i.e. put the validation code we're going to want to validate against in the `$_SESSION` or something along those lines (I'm assuming this isn't a hard coded value).

Comment: I am really confused to be honest.

Comment: @Becky Hope the examples help, don't be shy with the +1 if it did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input and the `onchange` listener:

```
<div id="validate">
    <label>Please provide your code</label>

    <!-- magic -->
    <input type="text" onchange="document.getElementById('validate-input').value = this.value;">

</div>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">

    <!-- this gets sent to the your PHP file -->
    <input type="hidden" id="validate-input" name="validate-input">

    <?php if (isset($error)){
        echo $error, '<br>';
    }?>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="firstname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('firstname')); ?>" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('lastname')); ?>" required>
    </div>
    <input id="signinButton" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: A simple solution, however this method exposes the validation code and could be prone to abuse, the OP stated in the Q/A comments on the question, that she was trying to prevent people that were not "invited" from being able to proceed, and this would very easily allow that for someone even a little in the know.